# Is there a way to suggest a rollback of a rollback?

Tags: support, rollbacks, rollback-wars

Yesterday I came across [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273416/the-view-or-its-master-was-not-found-or-no-view-engine-supports-the-searched-loc/31245642#31245642) that helped me, but I found it difficult to comprehend. So, I [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31245642/3) it to make it more readable. My edit did not change what the answer says, it changed *how* it was being said. The edit was approved, but then a few hours later the answer owner reverted my change.

Is there any way I can revert the owner's rollback? Or even flag it to have it looked at by a moderator? I would like to avoid a rollback-war.

Edit: Per comments and the answer, I have made a second [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31245642/5) that only changes the wording, not the intent. My edit has been approved.

Comment: There were a few grammatical errors that you could change as they're unambiguously incorrect, and you coudl expect a moderator to intervene if they're merely adding grammatical errors into a post, but there were several things that you changed that were changing what the answer actually says, or the way it chooses to convey that information.  If they feel that their prefered way is better, that's their decision to make.

Comment: @Servy my edit did not change what the answer said, it merely just made it understandable. I think the fact that someone thinks that my edit made the answer say something different should say something as to how poorly worded the original answer was.

Comment: @hashtagnatty I'm unfamiliar with the tag, but, you changed 'but you maybe need to call first constructor with object param' into 'You will need to call the overload with `object` as the second argument'. Their original answer said this *might* be required, while you changed it to say it's *absolutely* required.

Comment: @hashtagnatty Sure, but saying that the original was poorly worded doesn't make it okay for you to change it to say something other than what the author wants it to say.  If they feel that your wording is wrong, they can change it back, as they did.  If you're going to edit an answer, you need to actually know what it says and understand it well enough to be sure that it says the same thing after your edit.  If you don't know what it's supposed to say, you can't just edit it to say something arbitrary.

Comment: @Servy I do not disagree with you on the fact that they do have the right to change it back if I were to change the intent. However, I think you are either overlooking or misunderstanding the fact that my edit did NOT change the message of the answer. I know what it was trying to say. I don't quite get where you are coming from with this idea that either I changed what the answer intended or I didn't understand the answer. I'm not changing it to something arbitrary. Have a look at Alexei Levenkov's answer below. He points out that my edit made the answer more factually correct.

Comment: @Rob Okay, I see that. However, does that really, truly change the intent of the answer? I would argue not as that is such a small, technical detail. In essence the answer provides two possible solutions, both of which effectively result in using the same overload for View(..). My edit made this more clear than the original post.

Comment: @hashtagnatty Personally, yes, changing 'you might have to' to 'you must' *is* a pretty big change in the intent of the answer. In any case, though, your argument that you only made grammatical improvements and thus should have had the edit accepted really isn't correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you can flag the post for moderator's attention and provide detailed explanation of the request.

In this particular case while your edit made answer more factually correct (OP used "constructor" as name of a regular method) it is unlikely moderators will actually agree with your request: correctness of the posts is managed by community via votes and comments, OP of the post has final say on how post should look like. As result it is generally better to comment on the post and only after some time edit the post if OP is not responsive.

Note: you can claim you yet can't comment, but that can be fixed by you - so again no moderator action is necessary.

If you feel that you have much better information that is already provided in the answers you are welcome to add your own answer (if you base answer on existing once make sure to cite them appropriately).

Comment: The OP doesn't have the final say. The community deliberately has the ability to edit any post. The OP has as powerful tools as someone with 2k rep to modify their own post.

Comment: @Ben Unless the OP is making objectively bad edits, edit wars will *usually* be settled in favour of the OP.

Comment: @Ben while community indeed can edit any posts OP has reputation on the line (SO-reputation as well as general reputation). There were enough cases in the past where such suggested edits turned out to nasty 
"discussions" and by now I would not expect moderators to defend such edits (maybe with exception of super popular or locked questions with clearly wrong guidance ). There is also almost always alternative  route to provide better answer which can be done by any community member without any restrictions (sure, one needs 10rep for locked questions).